# How to get a clean copy when you switch a branch?

Tags: git

Let's assume I've been working in a feature branch and added a number of files there. They were successfully committed and pushed. Now I switch to master by `git checkout master` but all files are added in a feature branch are still there (physically, not staged in git). To get rid of them I have to call `git clean -fd`.

It's annoying to do every time. I expected something like `git checkout master -clean` should exist but it does not seem to be the case.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They were successfully committed and pushed

Make sure you committed all changes.

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git status           # see if all changes are committed
```

If you have uncommitted changes then `stash` them first, then checkout to other (say, `master`) branch

```
$ git add .
$ git stash

$ git status          # working directory should be clean now 
$ git checkout master
```

Or, You can `hard reset HEAD` instead of `stash`

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD     # back working directory to last commit
$ git status 
$ git checkout master
```

**Note:** `hard reset` is potentially dangerous since it move away all your uncommitted changes.

Comment: You're right. My bad. Those files were not committed.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the following sequence behaves as expected :

```
$ git status
old_b
$ git checkout -b nu_branch
$ echo "content" > fred
$ git add fred
$ git commit -m "added fred"
$ git checkout old_b
$ \ls fred 2> /dev/null | wc -l
0
```

I'd say you assumed too much. Could be you were not on new branch when you committed.